# How to get a value using SQL in Delphi and setting the value to a variable?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010

I'm trying to get the price of medication from the table but i just get:

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.BuyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iAmount : integer;
  rRate : real;
  sMedication : string;
  sRate : string;
begin
  iAmount := 0;
  sMedication := BuyCombobox.Items[BuyCombobox.ItemIndex];
  dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
  dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Add('SELECT Price(R) FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication = quaotedstr(sMedication)');
  sRate := dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL;
  ShowMessage(sRate);
end;
```

Comment: `dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL` is your sql text. Use `dmHospital.qryPrices.Open` instead.

Comment: Also  `dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Add('SELECT Price(R) FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication = quaotedstr(sMedication)');` is incorrect. Use  `'SELECT Price(R) FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication= ' + QuotedStr(sMedication)` instead.

Comment: Please do not post fake code in your q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the query properly. `qryPrices.SQL` is the SQL statement itself. It's just text. You need to do something to actually run the statement. (See below.)

You've also embedded the variable inside the quotes, which means it's not being evaluated, and neither is the function call to the (misspelled) `QuotedStr`. There is no function `quaotedStr()`. If you insist on the poor idea of concatenating SQL, you need to do it properly. If you're going to clear and then add, you can just assign to `SQL.Text` instead to do it in one step:

```
dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Price(R) FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication = ' + Quotedstr(sMedication);
```

Also, the query won't do anything until you actually execute it. You need to use `qryPrices.Open` to run a `SELECT` statement, or `qryPrices.ExecSQL` to run an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

You should get out of the thought of concatenating SQL immediately (before you get the habit) and learn to use parameterized queries. It allows the database driver to handle the formatting and conversion and quoting for you, and it also prevents SQL injection that can give others access to your data. Here's a corrected version that should get you started.

```
procedure TForm1.BuyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sMedication : string;
  sRate : string;
begin
  iAmount := 0;
  sMedication := BuyCombobox.Items[BuyCombobox.ItemIndex];
  dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Price(R) FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication = :Medication';
  dmHospital.qryPrices.Parameters.ParamByName('Medication').Value := sMedication;
  dmHospital.qryPrices.Open;
  sRate := dmHospital.qryPrices.FieldByName('Price(R)').AsString;
  dmHospital.qryPrices.Close;
  ShowMessage(sRate);
end;
```

Comment: should you not check if any record is returned in the dataset ?

Comment: @Guido: No. If no record is returned, then reading the field will return an empty string. Not sure why you downvoted my answer, since it is correct, does things properly, and contains a full explanation of what was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @GuidoG In most cases, this is not necessary.   If necessary, it may be checked the result.

Comment: @KenWhite i did not downvote you im not so triggerhappy as some people we are all here to learn

Answer (score 5):

You should modify Your code to actually work:
My advise is to use parameters instead of QuotedStr:

```
dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Clear;
dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Add('SELECT Price(R) AS Rate FROM MedicationPrices WHERE   Medication = :pMedication');
dmHospital.qryPrices.Params.ParamByName('pMedication').AsString=sMedication;
```

(Note that in ADOQuery You'd use .Parameters instead of .Params)

```
dmHospital.qryPrices.Open;
sRate=dmHospital.qryPrices.FieldByName('Rate').AsString;
ShowMessage(sRate);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not tested it (dont have Delphi at hand here) but it should be something like this :

```
iAmount := 0;  
sMedication := BuyCombobox.Items[BuyCombobox.ItemIndex];  
dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Clear;  
dmHospital.qryPrices.SQL.Add('SELECT Price(R) as price FROM MedicationPrices WHERE Medication = ' + QuotedStr(sMedication));  

dmHospital.qryPrices.Open;
if (dmHospital.qryPrices.RecordCount = 1)
  sRate := dmHospital.qryPrices.FieldByName('price').AsString;  

ShowMessage(sRate);
```

Comment: Boo for the string concatenation and use of RecordCount on a SQL dataset. (Use parameters and `IsEmpty` instead.) Don't teach new users bad technique; instead, teach them correctly from the start.

Comment: @GuidoG RecordCount is often implemented by fetching all the records from the server. That's okay if you're planning to iterate all the records anyway, but is best avoided if you're just checking if the result set is empty (use IsEmpty) or if you're displaying the data in a grid, which would fetch it as needed. This is not a problem on small result sets, but could be when there are millions of matching records. So it's best to form the habit to use IsEmpty for cases like this.

Comment: Thanks you just thought me something new.