# Can't find a field in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, delphi

I have a table containing the field 'cost', when I try to extract its value from the table I get an error saying the field was not found.

```
 function TSQLs.Get(value,room,hotel: string): string;
begin
  with Databasehub.DataModule1 do
  begin
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    ADOTable1.TableName:='TblRoom';
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT "'+value+'" FROM TblRoom WHERE RoomType="' + Room + '" AND HotelName 
    ="'+Hotel+'"');
    DataSource1.DataSet:=ADOQuery1;
    ADOQuery1.Open;
    if (ADOQuery1.RecordCount = 1) then
    begin
      Result := ADOQuery1.FieldByName(value).AsString;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Database table I'm extracting the value from]
[image: Table its linked to]

Comment: Hint: Instead of doing `ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear` followed by `ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(SQL)`, you can simply do `ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := SQL`.

Comment: Also, consider using parameterised queries instead of building them using string concatenation. Otherwise very bad and strange things can happen. What if the value contains a quotation mark, for instance?

Comment: If you want to get the amount in the Cost column, why do you confuse the issue by referring in your Sql to `Value`?  Do what @AndreasRejbrand said, but use this statement `AdoQuery1.Sql.Text := 'select cost from TblRoom where RoomType = ' + QuotedStr(Room)  + ' and HotelName = ' + QuotedStr(Hotel);`  or, better, use a parameterised query (see the Online Help),  And don't use double quotes (") in Delphi-constructed Sql.

Comment: sigh, I guess its hard to take good advice. Please please use parameters, do some [reading](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOQuery_Parameters.html) and you will find all your problems go away...

Comment: Do yourself a favour and study @KenWhite's answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145959/how-to-get-a-value-using-sql-in-delphi-and-setting-the-value-to-a-variable.  Note what he says in comments about the (lack of) need to check if no record is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an SQL statement, don't surround field names in double-quotes.  If a field name has spaces (or other special characters, or reserved names), use square brackets instead.  And since your field name is being provided by an input `string`, make sure to sanitize it before using it to avoid any SQL Injection attacks.

Also, you should be using single-quotes instead of double-quotes around string literals that are used in SQL statements:

```pascal
if Pos(';', value) > 0 or Pos(',', value) > 0 then raise ...;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [' + value + '] FROM TblRoom WHERE RoomType=' + QuotedStr(Room) + ' AND HotelName = ' + QuotedStr(Hotel);
ADOQuery1.Open;
...
```

A safer option to using literals is to use parameters instead (like [@whosrdaddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147655/65863) demonstrates), except that field names in a `SELECT` clause can't be parameterized, so that portion of the SQL will still have to use string concatenation (after sanitizing the string):

```pascal
if Pos(';', value) > 0 or Pos(',', value) > 0 then raise ...;
ADOQuery1.ParamCheck := True;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [' + value + '] FROM TblRoom WHERE RoomType=:Room AND HotelName=:Hotel';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Room').Value := room;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Hotel').Value := hotel;
ADOQuery1.Open;
...
```

Comment: Why did you use `['+ Value +']` instead of value and then using `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Value').Value := Value;`

Comment: @Umsugi: as stated in his answer, you cannot set field names with parameters, you must concatenate them if you want a dynamic query (and this is safe).

Answer (score 1):

First of all treat the values in your program as the type in the database.
Cost should be defined as a currency type in your Access DB, Delphi has a currency type too, use it as long as you can and only at presentation time, use conversion to text (or use a control that can handle the native type).
Also make sure to always use parameters in your queries, or else you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), as a bonus it makes your queries more readable and avoids problems like quotes in names etc...

Here is an example of a parametrized query and how to create a query on the fly

```
function TSQLs.GetCost(const Room : string; const Hotel: string): Currency;

var
  Qry : TADOQuery;
begin
 Qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
 try
  Qry.Connection := Databasehub.DataModule1.AdoConnection; // assign your TADOconnection here
  Qry.ParamCheck := True; // parse parameters
  Qry.SQL.Text :='SELECT Cost FROM TblRoom WHERE RoomType=:Room AND HotelName=:Hotel'; 
  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('Room').Value := Room;
  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('Room').DataType := ftString;
  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('Hotel').Value := Hotel;
  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('Hotel').DataType := ftString;
  Qry.Active := True; // Qry.Open is also fine here
  if not Qry.EOF then // don't rely on recordcount here as it could be 0 when using dynamic cursors for example
    Result := Qry.FieldByName('Cost').AsCurrency;
 finally
  Qry.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: The call to FieldByName could be replaced by Fields[0] as the query will return only a single field.

Comment: maybe, but doing this makes the code less verbose and in gets you in trouble once you add more fields. And the performance gain is negligible (unless you loop this for millions of records)

Comment: @whosrdaddy The reason I used  `.AsString` is because the code is in a function. So its easier to extract the value and then just convert it when I place it in a var.